# Sql Server ldf files growing very fast

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am using Sql Server 2012.
My **LDF** files are growing very fastly.
For example,
If I try to change the data type of a 3-4 columns from varchar(10) to varchar(5), then almost **4-5 GB** of disk space is consumed.

Even, when i run simple insert queries, a significant amount of disk space is consumed.

Please tell me What are the possible reasons for growing ldf files so fastly?
How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Also see http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/1186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Finally I got a chance to solve this problem.
Actually,
when I do perform transaction log backups, it doesn't free the space from ldf files.
So,
to solve it,
first of all, I take full backup of the database.
Then try to shrink the database (not files).
When I shrink the database, the space from the ldf files was freed.

This is what, that solved my problem.

[Visit This link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space) for more brief details as suggested by  **Aaron Bertrand**

Comment: @MikeDarwish not sure, but that's what worked for me back then. There must be some better solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in full recovery mode you need to perform regular transaction log backups in order to slow down the log growth.

```
USE master
GO
SELECT   a.name, 
         MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS backup_finish_date 
FROM     master.sys.sysdatabases a 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b 
         ON b.database_name = d.name 
         AND b.type          = 'L' 
GROUP BY a.name 
ORDER BY backup_finish_date DESC
```

Also, these are some of the factors which result in transaction log growth:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414.aspx

Also, this link may help you further in controlling the log file size: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/09/20/sql-server-how-to-stop-growing-log-file-too-big/

Comment: so i tried to perform a transaction log backup... but it deos not affect the ldf file size. ldf file is still having the same size as before. But, i should truncate the ldf file. (though i selected the turncate the transaction log option)... :(

Comment: ALSO, performing regular transaction log backups will slow down the log growth but the size of the ldf file remains the same... :(